# Write a script for modifying a text file and find a variable and replate it with the current time

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

Let me explain my goal first.
I want to make a WINRAR file of whole files within my destination folder.
I want to make WINRAR only from the newly created files and not the older files.

I have prepared the following script:
"c:\Program Files\winrar\Rar.exe" a -r -m0 -ta20140501 offsitebackup.rar e:\backup*

It says that WINRAR should make WINRAR file from all of the files which are modified after 2014 /05/01

I don't want to change the time frame on this script each week. so i need another script to modify this initial script

The second script needs to calculate the current time and subtract 7 days from the current date.

And then it should open my initial script and replace the initial time with the new time that should be there (current time minus 7 days)

I need a tool which be able to find "-ta" in my script and replace the numerals after that till a SPACE, with new time frame
This is my initial script:

"c:\Program Files\winrar\Rar.exe" a -r -m0 -ta20140501 offsitebackup.rar e:\backup*

After 7 days it should be changed like this:
"c:\Program Files\winrar\Rar.exe" a -r -m0 -ta20140508 offsitebackup.rar e:\backup*

I know how to do it with awk tool in linux, you can give it variable and also let is know where to find the specific part of the text and replace it with what we want

Comment: Did this get resolved? Is the answer below correct? If so, please mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

With your script below, using `%1` then you can use the following script to call it.

```
::myscript.bat
@echo off
"c:\Program Files\winrar\Rar.exe" a -r -m0 -ta%1 offsitebackup.rar e:\backup*
```

Note that the last line calls your script above:

```
:: 7days.bat
@echo off
set day=-7
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"
call "Myscript.bat" %data%
```